# nftables Named Set Update Delay

Tags: firewall, nftables, netfilter, set

I have the following in `nftables.conf`:

```
table inet nat {

        set blocked {
            type ipv4_addr
        }
        
        chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;

            ip daddr @blocked counter drop;
            
            oifname "ppp0" masquerade;
            iifname "br-3e4d90a574de" masquerade;
        }
    }
```

The set `blocked` is a [named set](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets#Named_sets) which can be updated dynamically. It is in this set I wish to have a collection of IPs to block, updated every *n* minutes. In order to preserve the [atomicity](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Atomic_rule_replacement), I am **not** using the following (`updateblock.sh`) to update the list:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo nft flush set inet nat blocked
sudo nft add element inet nat blocked {$nodes}
```

But rather `blockediplist.ruleset`:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush set inet nat blocked
add element inet nat blocked { <example_ip> }
```

I use the following order of commands:

```
nft -f /etc/nftables.conf
nft -f blockediplist.ruleset
```

However the changes in `blockediplist.ruleset` are not immediately applied. I know the ruleset now contains the new IPs because the IPs are present in `nft list ruleset` and `nft list set inet nat blocked`. Even just with `nft add element inet nat blocked { <IP> }` is the IP not being instantly blocked.

An alternative method would be to define a new set and reload `nftables.conf` in its entirety, though I think this would be a poor and inefficient way of doing things.

Is there a way to force the changes in `blockediplist.ruleset` to be applied immediately?

**UPDATE:** I've just discovered that when I block an IP which I haven't pinged, it gets blocked instantly. However when adding an IP to the blocklist mid-ping it takes a while for it to be blocked. When I try a set with `netdev ingress` the IP gets blocked instantly. Maybe this avenue of investigation might reveal something.

Comment: Why not create two sets and swap usage by updating one rule ip daddr @blocked counter drop;?

Comment: Also read https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg59583.html

Comment: Why do you need nft -f /etc/nftables.conf before nft -f blockediplist.ruleset?

Comment: However the changes in blockediplist.ruleset are not immediately applied. How do you know about that?

Comment: I know the changes aren't applied immediately because I'm still getting ICMP responses from the IP(s) I'm pinging. `nftables.conf` needs to be before because otherwise it will reset the set. Thanks for that link, I found [this](https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-buglog/2020-July/004919.html) so checked my version and it's `0.9.8`. The issue for me seems to be just that it doesn't start blocking for a while.

Comment: Are you want block access from sombody to you or from you to somebody? If first you should check saddr in prerouting

Comment: It's `postrouting` because I want the traffic to be blocked from whatever to the blocked IPs (even local processes on the router).

Comment: So you should block revers traffic also. Thats why you see replies from remote host. Remote send traffic to you in reply to your traffic until it figure out that somthing wrong . Its bidirectional thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nat hook (as all other hooks) is provided by Netfilter to nftables. The NAT hook is special: only the first packet of a connection is traversing this hook. All other packets of a connection already tracked by conntrack aren't traversing any NAT hook anymore but are then directly handled by *conntrack* to continue performing the configured NAT operations for this flow.

That explains why you should never use this hook to drop: it won't affect already tracked connections, NAT-ed or not.

Just change the hook type from `type nat` to `type filter` for the part dropping traffic. Contrary to *iptables* a table is not limited to one hook type and actually has to use multiple types for this kind of case, because the *set* is local to a table and can't be shared across two tables. For the same reason, this table should logically not be called `inet nat` anymore because it's not just doing NAT (but I didn't rename it).

So in the end:

`nftables.conf`:

```
table inet nat {

        set blocked {
            type ipv4_addr
        }

        chain block {
            type filter hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
            ip daddr @blocked counter drop
        }

        chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
            oifname "ppp0" masquerade
            iifname "br-3e4d90a574de" masquerade
        }
    }
```

Now:

- all packets will be checked by the `inet nat block` chain allowing the `blocked` set to immediately affect the traffic rather than having to wait for the next flow to be affected.
- as usual only the first packet of a new flow (tentative conntrack state NEW) will traverse the `inet nat postrouting` chain.

---

Please also note that `iifname "br-3e4d90a574de" masquerade;` requires a recent enough kernel (Linux [kernel >= 5.5](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=28f8bfd1ac948403ebd5c8070ae1e25421560059)): before only filtering by outgoing interface was supported in a postrouting hook. Also, this looks like a Docker-related interface, and adding this kind of rule might possibly interact with Docker (eg: it might do NAT on traffic between two containers in the same network) because it's referencing a bridge interface. That's because Docker makes bridged traffic seen by *nftables* (as well as *iptables*) by loading the [`br_netfilter` module](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html)).

Comment: Ah brill thanks. I should have been more attentive to the nftables documentation and my rules lol - feel like it's a bit of a silly error by oversight. Interesting point about the docker masquerade rule: it is used to give some containers WAN access, but inter-container communication is addressed by my bridge filter rules.

Comment: @SyntheticAscension I notice that you never accepted any of the answers (which happen to be mine) to your questions. Is there a reason? Do you know that you're supposed to mark an answer as the accepted answer when it solves your problem? For these two (incl. here) I have no doubt: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712571/nftables-egress-hook , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717533/nftables-named-set-update-delay and for this one I'm not sure what's your status: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631718/nftables-default-drop-chain-problem , can you check it too?

Comment: (thanks). Also, what I meant about br_netfilter (if you're using Docker: it's loaded by Docker, not by default) is that the same bridged frame with an IPv4 payload is seen both by nftables' bridge family filters, *and also* by nftables' ip and inet families filters, as weird as it can seem, with the conversion back and forth between frame and packet performed by br_netfilter.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I'll mark them now and be more concious of this in the future